# How do I get hold of a property of typescript object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code

```
submitData() {
    var search= new ProductSearch();
    search=this.profileForm.value;
    console.log(search);
    console.log(search.Code);
  }
```

The console.log(search) line produces

> {code: "123456"}

but the console.log(search.Code) line produces

> undefined

This is the ProductSearch object

```
export class ProductSearch {
    Code:string;
}
```

Comment: You have `code` and `Code`, those are different.

Comment: It would be `console.log(search.code)` , not `console.log(search.Code)`. Although once you assign the value to search it is no longer an instance of a class

Comment: it automatically turns "Code" to "code" when it writes the log. all the instances of "Code" in the application are with uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use var and use let or const 
Other than that u need to use simple c instead of C of code `console.log(search.code);`

Comment: *do not use var and use let or const* why?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava see https://evertpot.com/javascript-let-const/, https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/when-should-use-const-and-let-instead-of-var-in-javascript-ec2c3d7e5ca6

Comment: Links will serve no purpose here, I ask why because you include this statement in your answer, but it doesn't really address the problem OP is facing

Comment: if I change Code to code I get Property 'code' does not exist on type 'ProductSearch'. Did you mean 
'Code'?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I put it as a best practices and I added answer as well can u see it ?

Comment: Okay, so I also changed the object property to a lowercase c and everything works. Why on earth can I not use uppercase?

Comment: Point taken about the use of let over var.

Comment: @coolblue2000 ucan see it in tslint.config file
 "variable-name": [.......] and u can change it as well.. And it's better to use camel case u can follow style guide https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-04 and related question here https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-04

Comment: Thanks. That is useful to know. I will start using camel case.

Answer (score 0):

Form control name is code, you should change it to Code.Try like this.

```
export interface ProductSearch{
   Code:string
}

submitData() {
    const search:ProductSearch=this.profileForm.value;
    console.log(search);
    console.log(search.Code);
  }
```